# Laravel 3.5 - View [Index] Not Found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, deployment, routes, laravel-5.3

**UPDATE END** - **PROBLEM SOLVED**

The problem is that my server is not setting up properly because the domain doesnt connected properly to my VPS. Contacted the hosting provider and the problem solved.

If anyone have this problem just check

1. Have you already doing `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan
   config:clear`?
2. Did you name your view correctly with `yourview.blade.php`?
3. Did you place the view correctly in the `resources\views`?

---

I already deploy the laravel app into my VPS. It works fine on localhost.
the error message is shown below:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:  
View [index] not found.  

1.  in FileViewFinder.php line 137
2.  at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('E:\Laravel\portofolio\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79
3.  at FileViewFinder->find('index') in Factory.php line 174
4.  at Factory->make('index', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 856
5.  at view('index') in Portofolio.php line 56
6.  at Portofolio->link()
7.  at call_user_func_array(array(object(Portofolio), 'link'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
```

In line 2 of the error message, you can see that it's still in the local directory. I have tried using

```
php artisan config:clear|cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

and not even one has solved the problem. here is the view section in the config file after `php artisan config:cache` and as you can see its already using the VPS directory

```
'view' => 
  array (
    'paths' => 
    array (
      0 => '/home/wahyuhan/portofolio/resources/views',
    ),
    'compiled' => '/home/wahyuhan/portofolio/storage/framework/views',
  ),
```

Maybe the problem is in my route or controller page but I cant seems to find the problem there. The server OS is CentOS and I already read that CentOS is case-sensitive *but* I don't see any case sensitive problem in here.

Here is my server directory

```
Root
|-- portofolio
    |-- app
    |-- bootstrap
    |-- config
    |-- database
    |-- resources
        |-- assets
        |-- lang
        |-- views
            |-- index.blade.php
    |-- routes
    |-- storage
    |-- tests
    |-- vendor
|-- public_html
    |-- css
    |-- img
    |-- js
    |-- vendor
```

Here is my **ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'Portofolio@link']);
```

Here is my **CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Portofolio extends Controller
{
    public function link() {

        $categories = [
            '1' => 'Print Design',
            '2' => 'Logo Design',
            '3' => 'Web Design',
            '4' => 'Product Design',
            '5' => 'Character Design',
            '6' => 'Packaging Design'
        ];

        $projects = [
            '1' => 'IMSAA Training Certificate',
            '2' => 'Rusticity Logo',
            '3' => 'Handy Production Website',
            '4' => 'Nihon no Matsuri Bag Project',
            '5' => 'The Chin - Captain Jack Sparrow',
            '6' => 'Rusticity Packaging'
        ];

        $images = [
            '1' => '1',
            '2' => '2',
            '3' => '3',
            '4' => '4',
            '5' => '5',
            '6' => '6'
        ];

        $skills = [
            '1' => 'Photoshop',
            '2' => 'Ms. Office',
            '3' => 'Laravel',
            '4' => 'PHP',
            '5' => 'HTML',
            '6' => 'MySQL'
        ];

        $points = [
            '1' => '80%',
            '2' => '90%',
            '3' => '60%',
            '4' => '60%',
            '5' => '60%',
            '6' => '60%'
        ];

        return view('index')->withCategories($categories)->withProjects($projects)->withImages($images)->withSkills($skills)->withPoints($points);
    }
}
```

any advice?

Comment: Try to rename index blade to another.

Comment: @Rishi I tried to rename the **index.blade.php** to **home.blade.php** and doing `php artisan config:cache` but the _weird_ thing is the error is still the same `view [index] not found`

Comment: Run this command `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @Rishi Not working, still having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my server is not setting up properly because the domain doesnt connected properly to my VPS. Contacted the hosting provider and the problem solved.

If anyone have this problem just check

1. Have you already doing `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan
   config:clear`?
2. Did you name your view correctly with `yourview.blade.php`?
3. Did you place the view correctly in the `resources\views`?